# Can webpack determine if devDependencies are used when creating a production bundle?

Tags: webpack, nrwl-nx, dependabot

### tl;dr:

Is there a way to configure webpack (out-of-the-box or via some plugin?) to flag/raise a warning if the code getting bundled (for a production bundle) requires / imports any dev dependencies? (either directly via `devDependencies`, or indirectly via `dev: true` in `package-lock.json`)?

### Context

We are configuring dependabot to only scan packages declared in `dependencies` (this is achievable by using dependabot's [`allow`](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/configuration-options-for-the-dependabot.yml-file#allow) config option).

However, in order for this to be a reliable security process (as we are relying on dependabot's security vulnerability scanning), we need to have an automated process that ensure packages are correctly placed either in `dependencies` or `devDependencies`. One way to do this would be to have `webpack` emit a warning if any bundled code includes a `devDependency`.

Some further potentially relevant info:

This is for a monorepo managed by `nx` with

- a single `package.json` at the root
- two apps (`apps/frontend` and `apps/backend`)
- a few shared libraries (in `libs/*`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no Webpack plugin that can do this for you. There are some other dependency graph traversal modules/CLI tools that can generate these stats. The [depcheck](https://www.npmjs.com/package/depcheck) is one such module that I often use.

It can tell you about unused and missing modules, but not exactly what you seek. In general, it is hard to find that out. It may happen that what you declared as a `devDependency` may also be an actual `dependency` for some transitive package. Also, mandatory peer dependencies are also declared as dev dependencies which further complicate things. Finally, you may also have scripts which are meant only for development purpose and in those scripts, you may also import those dev dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Harshal. Is webpack not able to see if a transitive dependency is marked with `dev: true` in the package-lock.json? It _seems_ like it would be possible to resolve all that stuff

Comment: @jlb, It is possible but Webpack won't do it as different package managers have different lock files. Also, the format of the `package-lock` is not public. It is often subject to change.

Comment: Ok thanks. This means that in theory you could have a webpack plugin that is able to read package-lock.json (eg. for some specific version of npm’s package-lock.json format) and generate this information?